# Passenger on Debian failed with "only ET_DYN and ET_EXEC can be loaded"

Tags: debian, ruby, phusion-passenger

I tried to install passenger using rvm and ruby 1.9.2 on my debian lenny/sid today, but i get this error:

```
 apache2: Syntax error on line 295 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/conf.d/passenger.conf: 
 Cannot load /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/passenger-3.0.2/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.o into server: /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/passenger-3.0.2/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.o:   
 only ET_DYN and ET_EXEC can be loaded
   ...fail!
```

RVM was installed with

```
 bash < <( curl http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/releases/rvm-install-head )
```

after changing the bashrc I installed passenger with

```
 rvm install 1.9.2
 rvm default 1.9.2
 gem install passenger
 rvmsudo passenger-install-apache2-module
```

and than I added the lines printed out at the end into the passenger.conf.

What does the error mean? How can I get it running?

Comment: What does `file /home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/passenger-3.0.2/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.o` say?  `uname -a`?

Comment: file says this: `.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/passenger-3.0.2/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped` and uname says this: `2.6.18-028stab070.7 #1 SMP Fri Oct 1 13:53:00 MSD 2010 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: For some reason the apache2 module compile failed.  Apache modules should be "shared objects" (usually .so extension) which are the ET_DYN mentioned in the error message.  Not sure why passenger-install-apache2-module isn't telling you that.  Perhaps there's a "verbose" flag you can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangly the passenger instalation was somehow damaged. I went into the passenger dir and compiled the module by hand using `rake apache2` and after that I changed the .o into .so and now it's working perfectly.